# Node - Running a script irregularly in the background

Tags: javascript, node.js, timer, setinterval

I want my main Node.js application to run. So it takes care of a few routes, does DB queries and generates views. At startup a script is to be started, which executes the same operation in the background almost all the time (in a loop). This script should be initialised with data during startup, but should also be accessible while it is running. The script writes to the same database and in the best case it can tell the main Node.js application if something goes wrong.

---

I tried a little bit and asked myself if this approach is maybe the easiest solution. I set a timeout on the interval of the object and pass a function. In this function I execute my operation and set the next (slightly changed) interval, which I again realise with a timeout.
As I understand it the rest of my application just runs on and the functions defined in the timeout simply jump in between at the appropriate moment. If I want to interrupt the endless repetition, I can do this with the object created by the timeout function. (Not implemented in the code example).

**My only concern is, if this causes a recursion and I get an error if I repeat it too often?**

```js
function myFunc(obj) {
  
  // processing the object ...
  console.log("processing the objet: " + obj.objectID)

  // calculating next interval with slight change
  let newInterval = obj.interval + 3000 * Math.random() - 1500
  console.log("next process will start in: " + newInterval + " ms")
  
  // starting next cycle
  setTimeout(myFunc, newInterval, obj);

}

// sample object
let object = {
  objectID : 1,
  interval : 5000
}

// starting infinit loop
setTimeout(myFunc, object.interval, object);
```

---

Background:

*I would like to implement a feed reader in Node.js. The Node.js instance should receive the requests of the users and generate the respective views. At the same time, the feeds from the various feed sources are to be queried in the background. In order not to overload the capacity of the news pages from which I get the feeds, it is best practice to vary the intervals slightly randomly. Therefore a simple `setInterval()` will not work. Also note that the different sources have different update intervals. This goes from 5 minutes to 2 hours.*

**Which approach would be appropriate for the case presented? (worker_thread, a second independent node application, setTimeout() or something completely different)**

Comment: Maybe you need something like `cron` package to run something by schedule (and you can even use child_process for that): https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) - Yes, I thought about that too, but isn't cron there to execute commands **regularly**? I would like that the interval to the next execution is **recalculated with a small difference**. To do this with cron the cron job would have to delete itself and create a new one each time it is executed, or? I would have hoped there was a better solution.